# ANT to Remote Tomcat Deployment gets 500

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

So I made an ANT target to deploy our app to Tomcat on a remote development server. The ANT deploy to tomcat target works 100% perfect on a local Tomcat instance. When I deploy to the remote server I get a fat 500 error but the application actually deploys to the server and we can view and use it just fine as if there were no errors.

Super cool that it works but the 500 error causes the ANT target to say the build failed. If ANT says the build failed, so will Hudson our build server, which means we will have sad red dots instead of happy green ones.

We are using the latest and greatest ANT with Tomcat v9.

Below is the error I get when I execute my "ant deploy-dev" target.

---

`[username@localhost app.directory]$ ant deploy-dev
Buildfile: /home/username/git/app.directory/build.xml
Trying to override old definition of datatype resources`

deploy-dev:
     [echo] Deploying app to: https://dev.myapp.com

BUILD FAILED
/home/username/git/app.directory/build.xml:73: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/username/git/app.directory/build.xml:146: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://dev.myapp.com/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fmy-app%2F
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:854)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)

Total time: 3 minutes 3 seconds

---

To get an idea of what is running, here is the important parts of the ANT build.xml.

```xml
<property environment="env"/>
<property file="build.properties"/>

<!-- Import -->
<import file="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina-tasks.xml" optional="true"/>

<!-- The deploy to Tomcat target -->
<target name="deploy-local" description="Deploy the app to local Tomcat">
    <tomcat-deploy base-url="${url.base.local}"/>
</target>

<target name="deploy-dev" description="Deploy the app to dev Tomcat">
    <tomcat-deploy base-url="${url.base.dev}"/>
</target>

<target name="undeploy-local" depends="stop-local" description="Undeploy the app from local Tomcat">
    <tomcat-undeploy base-url="${url.base.local}"/>
</target>

<target name="undeploy-dev" depends="stop-dev" description="Undeploy the app from dev Tomcat">
    <tomcat-undeploy base-url="${url.base.dev}"/>
</target>

<target name="stop-local" description="Stop the app on local Tomcat">
    <tomcat-stop base-url="${url.base.local}"/>
</target>

<target name="stop-dev" description="Stop the app on dev Tomcat">
    <tomcat-stop base-url="${url.base.dev}"/>
</target>

<macrodef name="tomcat-deploy">
   <attribute name="base-url"/>
   <sequential>
        <echo>Deploying app to: @{base-url}</echo>
        <deploy url="@{base-url}/manager/text" username="${username}" password="${password}" 
                path="/${app.name}" war="file:${war.path}.war"/>
   </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="tomcat-undeploy">
   <attribute name="base-url"/>
   <sequential>
        <echo>Un-deploying app from: @{base-url}</echo>
        <undeploy 
                failonerror="no"
                url="@{base-url}/manager/text"
                username="${username}"
                password="${password}"
                path="/${app.name}"
            />
   </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="tomcat-stop">
   <attribute name="base-url"/>
   <sequential>
        <echo>Stopping the app at: @{base-url}</echo>
        <stop url="@{base-url}/manager/text" username="${username}"
                password="${password}" path="/${app.name}" />
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Anyone have any idea why the deploy to remote works but still returns an error? The error I get is kind of vague so I don't know what I could do to debug it.

Comment: Do you get any messages in the server's log file(s)?

Comment: I do not get any server errors. The app actually deploys just fine. I think it has to do with the server taking too long to actually deploy the app. Seems the target is waiting for a success response and it times out before it gets it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the server was taking too long to deploy the app. Somewhere the Tomcat Deploy target is waiting for a response from the server saying the app was deployed. Unfortunately the only error is the 500 and there is nothing else to go on.

The solution, I simply re-installed Tomcat with Version 9, up from 8, and everything turned on much faster and the build was successful.

I can't really say this is the best answer but I got everything working.Hopefully someone has a better solution one day.

Comment: Note that Tomcat 9 hasn't yet had a stable release. Tomcat 8.5 might be more reliable for you.